# Counting Sort in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

In a PHP project I have some data I want to sort using a linear time, simple counting sort:

```
$ar = array(7, 2, 0, 3, 8, 0, 12, 7, 6, 7);
$count = array();
foreach ($ar as $v)
    $count[$v]++;
$sorted = array();    
foreach ($count as $v => $c)
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++)
        $sorted[] = $v;
```

The problem is that the above obviously doesn't work. The php array works more like a hashmap than an array. The code can be made to work by inserting `ksort($count)` before the final loop, but `ksort` runs in `O(nlogn)` which destroys the entire point.

Is there any way to do a linear time sort in php? Perhaps using some paramter to `array()`, or some entirely different structure?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the array based on how many times an item occurs in that array? So in your above example "7" would be first because it occurs more (3) times than any other number?

Comment: The above is supposed to leave `$sorted` as a sorted version of $ar. That is `array(0,0,2,3,6,7,7,7,8,12)`. Currently it gives `array(7,7,7,2,0,0,3,8,12,6)`.

Comment: So speed is not an issue, but it needs to run linear?

Comment: Despite the little fixes needed in your algorithm, you were right. The accepted answer is O(nlogn) too! May be, as you suggested, is related with the inner use of hybrid hash tables instead of classical arrays.

Comment: I just tried using [SplFixedArray](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php), and it grows like O(nlogn) too, and is slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't follow the [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) correctly. This is O(n).

```
$ar = array(7, 2, 0, 3, 8, 0, 12, 7, 6, 7);
$count = array();
foreach ($ar as $v) {
    $count[$v] = isset($count[$v]) ? $count[$v] + 1 : 1;
}
$sorted = array();
$min = min($ar);
$max = max($ar);
for ($i=$min; $i<=$max; $i++) {
    if (isset($count[$i])) {
        for ($j=0; $j<$count[$i]; $j++) {
            $sorted[] = $i;
        }
    }
}
```

also, see [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/array_count_values)(), or alternatively compute the min and max inside the counting loop.

Comment: What about the second one, can you make an array default to 0?

Comment: you can use [array_fill](http://www.php.net/array_fill)(), but that creates real entries in the array. [array_fill](http://www.php.net/array_fill) and [array_merge](http://www.php.net/array_merge) could replace the inner most for loop though, I just didn't want to get fancy.

Comment: @ThomasAhle: Drop that function, even if it's `O(n)`, it's much more slower than PHP's interal `sort()`. You're comparing complexity at the wrong place.

Comment: Nice answer, but there is a little bug in your for - test. In your sorted array "sorted" you have missed the element with the value "12". This can be fixed by using "$i<=$max" instead of "$i<$max" in the for - test!

Comment: I did some benchmarking. Using `array_count_values()` made the algorithm a **20% faster**, while computing `min` and `max` inside the counting loop made it **20% slower**. By the way, is not O(n) in PHP. Is O(nlogn) instead. May be is related with the inner use of hybrid hash tables instead of classical arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Approved answer is wrong. Correct:

```
$ar = array(7, 2, 0, 3, 8, 0, 12, 7, 6, 7);
$count = array();
foreach ($ar as $v) {
    $count[$v] = isset($count[$v]) ? $count[$v] + 1 : 1;
}
$sorted = array();
$min = min($ar);
$max = max($ar);
for ($i=$min; $i  <=   $max; $i++) {
    if (isset($count[$i])) {
        for ($j=0; $j<$count[$i]; $j++) {
            $sorted[] = $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, from a quick comparison, I can see no difference.

Comment: Is it wrong because of style or wrong as in just wrong... why would it get approved if it were wrong?

Comment: He is right! The for - test was not correct ... In the answer above the element "12" is missing. The right for - test is "$i<=$max" instead of "$i<$max"!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question AND comment correctly, just using sort($count) would work no?

```
$ar = array(7, 2, 0, 3, 8, 0, 12, 7, 6, 7);
$sorted = $ar;
sort($sorted);
var_dump($ar);
var_dump($sorted);
```

Result:

```
array(7,2,0,3,8,0,12,7,6,7);
array(0,0,2,3,6,7,7,7,8,12);
```

But i'm wondering what the foreach($ar as $v)$count[$v]++;  does... doesn't really make sense...

Comment: The question is called "Counting sort" because I'm looking to implement a counting sort. Counting sort has the advantage of running in `O(n+k)` where k is the size of the largest element. `sort()` runs in `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: Still, the result is the same no? Quicksort is slow if you have thousands of elements, but PHP is usually not meant to process that kind of information. You use MySQL do to so. So what is the means of the question in the end if i might ask?

Comment: Teaching the quirks of php I guess :) And in the case where you have data well suited for counting sort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To get the sorted `$ar` in a variable of it's own (`$sorted`), it's pretty trivial:

```
$sorted = $ar;
sort($sorted);
```

Which makes me think that your question and comment is not giving the whole picture.

**Edit:** Now after you have clarified that you wanted to implement a specific algorithm (and you actually got an answer already that shows some points that were wrong implementing it first), I think it's worth to focus on another aspect of your question:

You're comparing the complexity of two (theoretical) algorithms, but you're leaving aside how the algorithms are implemented.

PHP's `sort()` - even based on "bad" *quicksort*, will outrun your own PHP usercode implementation of some other algorithm *by numbers*.

You just have compared the wrong parameters here. The complexity of a function does not says much when you compare a build-in PHP function with some function in your user-code.

Comment: Yeah had the same bogus running... Question is either not clear or problem is overly simple...

Comment: The PHP `sort` is a quicksort, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php That means in runs worst case `O(n^2)` and `O(nlogn)` in average.

Comment: There are other sort algorithms, which one would you prefer if you think *quicksort* is too slow?

Comment: @hakre: Counting sort obviously ;)

Comment: @ThomasAhle: Edited the answer, the complexity you talk about are two pair of shoes. You can't compare those two functions which each other unless you metric in your specific case.

Comment: I never said I wanted to use this to outperform quicksort (even though it might in some cases). I just wanted to know how to do counting sort in php.

Comment: Might? It will for sure nerver outperform `sort` - which does the same. If you're looking how to implement the countedsort function for learning purposes, why didn't you write that clearly in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Adding some comments to the code to show you why this doesn't do what you think it should do.

```
$ar = array(7, 2, 0, 3, 8, 0, 12, 7, 6, 7);

$count = array();
foreach ($ar as $v) {
    // add each number in $ar to $count.
    // the first number in $ar is 7, so 7 will be the first number in $count.
    // because 7 is in $ar 3 times, $count[7] == 3.
    $count[$v]++;
}

// the output of print_r will be very revealing:
print_r($count);
/*Array
(
    [7] => 3
    [2] => 1
    [0] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [12] => 1
    [6] => 1
)*/

$sorted = array();    
foreach ($count as $v => $c) {
    // the first entry: $count[7] == 3
    // so add 7 to $sorted 3 times.
    // the second entry: $count[2] == 1
    // so add 2 to $sorted 1 time.
    // etc.
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $sorted[] = $v;
    }
}
```

This simply groups numbers together based on their location in the first array.

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote in the question, the code "obviously doesn't work". I just wanted to show you the algorithm you would use in C or Java. I hoped somebody could tell me a way to make it work in php (in the proposed complexity).

Answer (score 0):

```
$A = [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 0]; // example array
$m = max($A);
$count = array_fill(0, $m + 1, '0');
foreach ($A as $value) $count[$value] += 1;
       // next step is print the numbers 
$a = [];
foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $value;) {
        array_push($a, $key);;
        $i++;
    }
}

var_dump($count); // print the sorted array
var_dump($a); // print the numbers (low to high)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).